# Can't Access 'in_app' fields from iOS7 receipt on PHP Server

Tags: php, ios7, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, receipt-validation

I'm trying to grab the original transaction id from an iOS reciept but it's in a weird format when I use json_decode on the data I get back from apple. Here is an example:

//object from apple

```
   {
        "in_app" =  
         (
                 {
                    "is_trial_period" = false;
                    "original_purchase_date" = "2014-04-24 15:15:19 Etc/GMT";
                    "original_purchase_date_ms" = 1398352519000;
                    "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2014-04-24 08:15:19 America/Los_Angeles";
                    "original_transaction_id" = 1000000108799609;
                    "product_id" = Gems500;
                    "purchase_date" = "2014-04-24 15:15:20 Etc/GMT";
                    "purchase_date_ms" = 1398352520000;
                    "purchase_date_pst" = "2014-04-24 08:15:20 America/Los_Angeles";
                    quantity = 1;
                   "transaction_id" = 1000000108799609;
                 }
        );
    }
```

I see in other examples that in_app is an array but I'm getting it with round brackets. Not sure whats going on. This is my server method:

```
  // parse the response data
        $data = json_decode($response);

 $data = json_decode($response);

        // ensure response data was a valid JSON string
        if (!is_object($data)) {
            return 'Invalid response data';
        }

        // ensure the expected data is present
        if (!isset($data->status) || $data->status != 0) {
            return "Apple return with error ".$data->status;
        }

       $in_app = $data->receipt->in_app; //works fine
       $original_transaction_id = $in_app['original_transaction_id'];//does not work
```

Not sure why I'm getting round brackets or what to do but if you recognize this type of JSON response or perhaps something I'm doing wrong Im all ears.

All other fields from the receipt I can access, its only fields inside in_app I can't.

Comment: Two questions for you. 1) Is the first output above on your server in PHP, or locally on your iOS device? This looks like what I call "not quite json" and I see it as output on an iOS device. It seems to result from description method calls to NSDictionary's and NSArray's. 2) Have you tried: $purchase = $in_app[0]; $original_transaction_id = $purchase['original_transaction_id'];

Comment: This is as it appears in my iOS yes, but if I do $reciept['original_transaction_id'] I get null.